# Swift - Update a value in RootViewController from AppDelegate when the app comes to background state

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple view application with one main view only.

I'm trying to show updated time value in a label inside a view when the app comes to background state.

The scenario is:

1 - Single View Application project

2 - Only one View (ViewController) with one Label to show the date

3 - In the AppDelegate:applicationWillEnterForeground get the current time

```
func applicationWillEnterForegound(application: UIAPplication){
    var date:String = GetDate()
    --> update View Label with date here
}
```

4 - Show the current time on ViewController

I'm trying with delegates, but the problem is that the view was the last visible element in the app and methods as viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear are called once.

Comment: It's better to use the NSNotificiation in this case

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As others have noted, you can use the Notification framework to do this from within your view controller so your appDelegate does not need to reference your view controller.  Add a line like this in your controller:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(appWillEnterForeground), 
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,
    object: nil
```

In Swift 3 the syntax changes slightly:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
    selector: #selector(appWillEnterForeground),
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,
    object: nil)
```

In Swift 4.2 the syntax changes again:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
    selector: #selector(appWillEnterForeground), 
    name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, 
    object: nil)
```

then define the function you name in the selector:

```
@objc func appWillEnterForeground() {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of, this was very helpful

Comment: small additional change for swift3: name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,

Comment: since you are observing for after something goes to the background, when would remove the observer? Wouldn't removing it `viewDidDisapear` remove the observer when it goes into the background ?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` inside your `ViewController`.  If you know its views are visible, it can find the date and change its own label.

Comment: Thanks, with your answers I searched info about listeners and I found interesting discuss about it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for the answer. I implemented now a Notification in the main view and solve the problem.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateDate), name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}

func updateDate(){
    labelInfo.text = theDate
}
```

Thanks